# Syle not getting applied to dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I've been tinkering with this a little bit as well and can't quite understand why the styles get applied to the search text box but not the dropdown like it does on the template. Any ideas on why this could be happening.

http://jsfiddle.net/NNk7s/2/

Template: http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/peach/tables.html

Comment: Come on seriously here.  You dump a page on us and all you say is "style not getting applied to dropdown".  What drop-down, what is it's object id, what style rule are you expecting to have applied to that drop-down and what CSS file is that rule in.  We don't know your site - if you want some help you should tell us a LOT more about the problem rather than make us do detective work in order to help you and try to guess.

Comment: Try simplifying your code example.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm talking about the dropdown thats next to show entries. It should be styled the same way as the dropdown on the template page. Both elements are dynamically created with dataTables plugin. The text search text box is getting styled but not the dropdown and not sure why.

Comment: Where do the style rules come from?  CSS or applied by Javascript?  If CSS, which rules in which file?  If by Javascript, which function creates the object in which JS file?  You are expecting way too much for us to know how your site works and where to find this stuff.

Comment: I want to show you to be easier. Could you send me an IM on AIM or yahoo? (xtremer360)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see what's happening, although I don't know enough about this plugin to tell you why. There are two "dropdown menus" in the working example. One is a real HTML `<select>` tag with `<option>` tags, but this form element is hidden with a `style="display: none"` attribute.

What you're seeing on the page is actually a fancy, styled `<div>` tag designed to look like a  dropdown menu. The `<select>` tag is likely only there for compatibility with older browsers, or maybe if the user has JavaScript disabled.

You'll need to figure out what you need to do to get the plugin to create that fake dropdown overlay for you. It's probably just a matter of creating a `<div>` or some other element and applying a CSS class to it.

Comment: Everything is dynamically created though.